# Cisco ASA 5505 Issue - "Flags SYN on interface.."

Tags: firewall, cisco, routing, cisco-asa

I've been trying to remotely configure a Cisco ASA 5505 in front of a dedicated server hosted with OVH. Unfortunately my qualifications and even experience very rarely touched on Firewalls. However I went ahead and gave it a go, honestly I thought I had it but no joy.

Currently I'm just trying to get RDP working. I created the various network objects and created the access rule. However no matter what changes I make, the firewall rejects my RDP connection attempts with nothing more than this error:

[image: enter link description here]

The firewall is in transparent mode, 2 configured interfaces (inside and outside). I can find very little online other than mentions of interface security levels. I altered that to test and still no joy. The only other results I could find point to static routes, but from what I can tell there isn't any additional static route required due to the firewall being in transparent mode.

Below are some screenshots of various settings in a single image (sorry about this, I can't post more than 2 image links without reputation).

Cisco Config Sections:

[image: Cisco Config Sections]

Any advice or assistance would be greatly appreciated. I hope I have included all appropriate information, if I haven't I will amend my post.